# Displaying single symbol in legend for proportional symbol layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, line, legend

I'd like to be able to show just one line in the legend for my layer of multiple proportional symbols. Previously, my workaround was to create a secondary layer not displayed on the map, and to bring that into the legend to serve as a "dummy" symbol. But now, the client wants a .lyr file with symbology preserved, so I must be able to replicate a single-line legend feature.

Is there any way to do this in ArcMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the proprieties, the symbology tab has a list where you can choose the number of symbol (between 0 and 12) to show in the legend (at least in my 10.3 version)[image]

Comment: Of course! I realize now that I was using graduated symbols (where this option does not exist), but proportional symbols address the same problem. Also, it's a good thing I know how to read French!

Comment: Follow-up, is there a way to do this with graduated symbols?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with graduated as you have one symbol by class (unless you set only one class, but that's not really graduated in that case)